# Passing Data From Activity to another and then passing to fragment in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment, android-bundle

I'm trying to pass data from my `MainActivty` to another one with `ViewPager`, and get that data in the `Fragment`.

I tried so may ways but the app crashed every time.

here is my Classes:

**My Holder:**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(main_rv_holder holder, int position) {
  holder.name.setText(mains.get(position).getName());
  holder.image_main.setImageResource(mains.get(position).getImg());

  //Clicked
  holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(context,ViewerActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra("title",mains.get(position).getName());
      intent.putExtra("pos",position);
      context.startActivity(intent);
    }
  });
}
```

**My Activity with pager:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewer);
  //Toolbar Initialization
  InitializeToolbar();
  //ViewPAGER Initialization
  InitializePager();
  //Floating Action Button
  Fabinitialize();

  //pass data
  Bundle data = new Bundle();
  //Use bundle to pass data
  Form1 fragmentobj = new Form1();

  data.putString("tag","Hello");
  fragmentobj.setArguments(data);
}
```

**Fragment in the ViewPager:**

```
public class Form1 extends Fragment {
  String TAG;

  public Form1() {
    TAG = getArguments().getString("tag");
    // Required empty public constructor
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_VIew);
    textView.setText(TAG);

    return view;
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: why are you passing data so many times? Just save that data in shared preference or db and then access it directly in view pager

Comment: i want the fragments to load a different data when you click on a position and choose a category, so i want the fragment to know what was clicked to load the appropriate data @VivekMishra

Comment: You can access intent in fragment directly like  getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("key");

Comment: can you tell me how because i tried that too it didnt work @SuryaPrakashKushawah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below code

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_VIew);
    String title= getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
        textView.setText(title);

            return view;
        }
    }
```